# Have a problem joining two queries in MySQL

Tags: mysql, correlated-subquery

Am trying to join two queries  in mysql in phpmyadmin. it is giving me the following error:   #1142 - SELECT command denied to user 'cpses_dikfgmbqhy'@'localhost' for table 'lGroup'

Bellow is the query

```
SELECT
    AccountNum,
    GroupName,
    mFName,
    mSName,
    FacilityID,
    lGroup,
    LRate,
    PrincipleAmount,
    Interest,
    TotalLoan,
    Installment,
    PeriodOfFacility,
    FstInstallmentDate,
    FinalInstallmentDate,
    fUser
FROM
    GroupMemberQ
 JOIN AuthorisedLoans.lGroup ON GroupMemberQ.AccountNum  = AuthorisedLoans.lGroup
```

After joining them I want to have loans for each group

Comment: Sounds like your user does not have the permission to read that table

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: See [GRANT Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html) and study permissions system.

Comment: Thanks Nico and Akina. Am asking if you can show me how to change the privileges of a user in phpmyadmin so that this error can be resolved.